# Mongoose query on last item in array

Tags: mongoose

I would like to construct a Mongoose query to query against a field nested in an array. Each document in the collection may have a different length array, and I only want to query against the last entry in each array.

Here's my document structure:

```
User:
-- authData
   -- []
      --username
         --value
i.e, 

UserSchema = new Schema({
  authData: [{
    username: {
       value: String
    }
  }]
})
```

Here are some of my very naive approaches so far. The first doesn't compile, and the last one gets runtime errors ("Cannot read property 'username' of undefined")
:

```
Approach 1:
   UserObj.find({authData[authData.length].username.value: 'john'}, function(err, docs){});

Approach 2:
        UserObj.find({}, function(err, docs){
            docs.filter(doc =>
                doc['authData'].filter((itm,idx,arr)=>{
                    arr[itm.length-1].username.value === 'john'
                }));
    . . .
```

How can I construct the query properly?

Comment: arr[arr.length-1] should be like that no? instead of "arr[itm.length-1]"

Answer (score 0):

Missed something obvious previously . . . The answer is:

```
     UserObj.find({}, function(err, docs){
         let result = docs.filter(doc =>
             doc['authData'].filter((itm,idx,arr)=>{
                 arr[arr.length-1].username.value === 'john'
     }));
```

Or Slightly more elegant/complete version:

```
            let result = docs.
                map(doc=>doc['authData'].pop()).
                filter(auth => 
                         auth.username.value === req.query.username).
                map(itm=>itm.username.value);    
                res.json(JSON.stringify(result));   
                })
```